# How to install a library using homebrew

Tags: python, homebrew

I downloaded the QJson python library using `brew install qjson`.

What are the next steps I need to take in order to be able to work with it in PyCharm?

Comment: Why did you install it with Homebrew? PyCharm has a package manager built right in: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.1/installing-uninstalling-and-upgrading-packages.html, which will install the package for the currently-active interpreter/virtualenv

Comment: you're right, didn't think about that but i guess it would be still good to know in case i switch.

Comment: In general you use `pip` to install Python packages, not `brew` - again, *why* did you do it that way? The [package docs](https://github.com/imzjy/qjson) suggest using pip.

Comment: Yeah it doesn't say that on the package website, only in the git repo i guess. Since i'm new to OSX i thought homebrew is the best way to go, i guess i was wrong..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others mentioned already: It's not the best idea - at least not in general - to install python packages via your systems package manager. It's better to use pip (ideally in conjunction with virtualenvs).

Apart from that, it should be possible to use the package you installed using homebrew from pycharm / python in general. In pycharm you can switch between different interpreters (Settings / Project / Interpreter). You need to to choose the one you installed the package for with homebrew (e.g. the one in /usr/local/Cellar/python//..).

If you used brew link the currently active one should be symlinked to  /usr/local/bin/python.

Answer (score 0):

In pycharm you can go to the project interpreter page and click the + icon. 
Just like this [guide](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.1/installing-uninstalling-and-upgrading-packages.html#d127687e164) how to install libraries. I think you cannot do it with homebrew and this is certainly a lot easyer.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.